# Acquire the variable id name of children dom elements in PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to parse a website to acquire a specific id number, and the part of the site i am interested in looks like this:

```
<div class="clearfix" id="topCurrentGamesList">
    <div class="topCurrentGames" id="topCurrentGame38632" data-game-id="4154">
    </div>
    <div class="topCurrentGames" id="topCurrentGame38639" data-game-id="4161">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i'm trying to get the numbers placed in the id of the children, in this case name **38632** and **38639**. The code below i have used to select to parent div to both of the desired divs, as that has a static name.

```
$gameID = $dom->getElementById( 'topCurrentGamesList' );
```

The two children divs will get a new id from time to time though, and i want to extract that. Is it still DOM that is what i should be using and if so how? Or is there a much more elegant (simpler) solution to this?

print_r($gameID); displays this:

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => div
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => div
    [nodeValue] => 




    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => div
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 




)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using DOMDocument and DOMXPath is appropriate for this task. You just need to loop through each of the selected nodes and collect the "id" attributes:

```
<?php

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@id="topCurrentGamesList"]/div[@class="topCurrentGames"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $id = preg_replace('/^topCurrentGame/', '', $node->getAttribute('id'));
  // do something with $id
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that looks neat! I just discovered though that in my eager to make the html readable i removed a bit to much and the class is instead "topCurrentGames arenaActive". How do i handle the space in the name here? I tried just using that but the DOMNodeList Object came up empty.

Comment: You'll either need to match the class attribute exactly (e.g. `//div[@id="topCurrentGamesList"]/div[@class="topCurrentGames arenaActive"]`), use a less specific selector (e.g. `/div[@id="topCurrentGamesList"]/div[contains(@class, "topCurrentGames")]`), or leave the class attribute out of the selector (e.g. `'//div[@id="topCurrentGamesList"]/div`).

Comment: Hmm, i've tried those and all others i could think of and the DOMNodeList comes up empty all the time, odd.

Comment: If i run `$xpath->query('//div[contains(@id, "Game")]');
print_r($nodes);` the result i get is only topCurrentGamesList, not the other two.

Comment: Found the issue, the code for that part of the site is generated with javascript thus not visible when i parse the page with loadHTML. Damn.